# box viewer for microsoft office documents

Tags: c#, box-view-api

I have a quiz website, where user will select the topic and can read contents.

So I have contents in various formats like video, textfile, pdf reports.

For contents to show them in box I am using http://viewerjs.org/.
since it supports limited extensions and doesn't fill up my all requirements for file type- `.docx`,`.doc`, `.xlsx`,`.pptx`.

Is there any open source box viewer that supports office document?

Although I can read their contents through `c#` and display them back as plain text but my primarily requirement is to show them in box as viewer.js does it for pdf.

Comment: What is a "box viewer"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are conflating http://viewerjs.org/ with the [Box View API](http://developers.box.com/view/), which has an open-source viewer component that is also called [viewer.js](https://github.com/box/viewer.js).

The View API will convert Office file formats as well as `.pdf`.

The View API does not have a C# SDK available yet (as far as I know), but there are a [bunch of open source ones in other languages](https://trello.com/c/RvAGjCA5/36-sdks).